# LinkedHashSet: "contains" issue

Tags: contains, linkedhashset

What is the problem of this code?

```
Set<String> A = new LinkedHashSet<String>(); 
Set<String> B = new LinkedHashSet<String>();
Set<String> C = new LinkedHashSet<String>();

// A and C are filled before the piece of code below:

for (String ce: A){
   if (!C(ce))
     B.add(ce);
}
```

There are some Strings in A that are not in C. Hence, I expect that B has some elements but it is always empty when I print it. Note: this happens also with ArrayList.

Thank you.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the syntax `if (!C(ce))`.  What is this supposed to be doing?

Answer (score 0):

Correct instruction:

```
if(!C.contains(ce))
```

I want to check if a String in A is NOT in the LinkedHashSet C. All strings that are not in C should then be added to B. Thanks.